# How do I set a Combox with a default value when the Drop Down Style is set to "Dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I've been trying to get my combo box to set a default value using a record from a Database.  I have the Drop Down Style set to "Drop Down List" and this is the code I am Using.

First I am loading the listbox from the state data table into the combo box

```
Private Sub frmABS3_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        modABS.clsABS.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tblABSStates")
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(modABS.clsABS.Exception) Then MsgBox(modABS.clsABS.Exception) : Exit Sub

        For Each r As DataRow In modABS.clsABS.DBDT.Rows
            cboState.Items.Add(r("StateAbbrev"))
        Next
End Sub
```

Next I am populating the fields on the Form.  This is the part I am having trouble.

```
Private Sub GetRecord()
        ' Fail if No Records Found or position is out of Range
        If modABS.clsABS.DBDT.Rows.Count < 1 OrElse CurrentRecord > modABS.clsABS.DBDT.Rows.Count - 1 Then Exit Sub

        'Return first user found
        Dim r As DataRow = modABS.clsABS.DBDT.Rows(CurrentRecord)

        'Populate Fields
        cboState.Text = r("StateAbbrev").ToString
        txtCity.Text = r("City").ToString
End Sub
```

When I run the code the combo box doesn't show the state abbrev and the item isn't selected on the list.  It works the way its suppose to when I reset the Drop Down Style set to "Drop Down", however I don't want the user to be able to add a value that is not in the combo listbox.

Comment: Try the `SelectedItem` property instead of the Text property.

Comment: I tried cboState.selecteditem = r("StateAbbrev").ToString still not selecting :(

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have a value in `r("StateAbbrev")`?

Comment: Have you checked what `r("StateAbbrev").ToString()` contains at that point (before setting the `.SelectedItem` property, of course)? Is `r("StateAbbrev")` actually a column of type string or something else?

Comment: I tested the value with a variable and r("StateAbbrev") is returning "MI" (Michigan). I tried using the variable instead of the field reference.  It is still not displaying.

Comment: I found the problem the problem.  The 1st part of the code needed to be in the Load event not the shown event.

Answer (score 0):

This code needed to be in the form load event not the form shown event:

```
Private Sub frmABS3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    modABS.clsABS.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tblABSStates")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(modABS.clsABS.Exception) Then MsgBox(modABS.clsABS.Exception) : Exit Sub

    For Each r As DataRow In modABS.clsABS.DBDT.Rows
        cboState.Items.Add(r("StateAbbrev"))
    Next
    txtZipCode.Text = modABS.clsABS.ZipCode
End Sub
```